# How to improve the following query

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

I need to get a list of all users for a given provider. A user may have multiple providers, and a provider may have multiple users. Here is what I have so far:

I have the following tables:

```
class Provider(models.Model):
    provider = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, primary_key=True)
    provider = models.ManyToManyField(Provider, db_column='provider')
```

In my view:

```
providers = Provider.objects.order_by('provider')
```

And in my template:

```
{% for provider in providers %}
<tr>
    <td class="provider">
        {{ provider.provider }}
    </td>
    <td class="email">
        {% for profile in provider.userprofile_set.all %}
            {{ profile.user }}
        {% endfor %}    
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

This produces about 250 queries, as I'm iterating over the Provider QuerySet in the template. How would I improve the above -- is there a way to use `prefetch_related` or `select_related` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`prefetch_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related); `select
_related()` doesn't work on `ManyToManyField`s:

```
providers = Provider.objects.order_by('provider').all().prefetch_related('userprofile_set')
```

From the docs:

> Returns a `QuerySet` that will automatically retrieve, in a single batch, related objects for each of the specified lookups.
>
> This has a similar purpose to `select_related`, in that both are designed to stop the deluge of database queries that is caused by accessing related objects, but the strategy is quite different.
>
> ...
>
> `prefetch_related`, on the other hand, does a separate lookup for each relationship, and does the 'joining' in Python. This allows it to prefetch many-to-many and many-to-one objects, which cannot be done using `select_related`, in addition to the foreign key and one-to-one relationships that are supported by `select_related`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using django but i just found the answer here: [docs.djangoproject.com](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)

```
providers = Provider.objects.select_related().order_by('provider').all()
```

Comment: yeah, that's how I initially tried it, no improvement at all.

Comment: The all would be redundant in this case -- (testing it out was the exact same).

Comment: Maybe `select_related(depth=X)` helps?